# Contador até um número em específico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho três contadores, que vão até um certo número, definido em `data-count-to` de cada tag, o meu problema aqui é que gostava que eles atingissem o seu limite ao mesmo tempo, mesmo com valores tão diferentes como é o caso em baixo:

```js
function count_up(ele, count_to, timer, i) {
 if(i > count_to) {
  return;
 }
 ele.text(i.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1."));
 i += 1;
 /*console.log(timer);*/
 setTimeout(function() {count_up(ele, count_to, timer, i)}, timer);
}
$('.counter-up').each(function() {
 count_to = parseInt($(this).data('countTo'));
 timer = parseInt(40000/count_to);
 count_up($(this), count_to, timer, 0)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="counter-up" data-count-to="5684"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="counter-up" data-count-to="6603146"></span></div>
<div>
  <span class="counter-up" data-count-to="20362"></span>
</div>
```

Agora, eu acho que o meu problema é matemática neste caso, pois suspeito que tenha também de mexer na quantidade a incrementar também, e não só no tempo.

Gostaria que o resultado final fosse apenas que o argumento a variar seja o tempo, mas com quaquer tempo que os três contadores cheguem ao final respetivo ao mesmo tempo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É de facto uma questão de matemática. A minha resolução propõe aumentar a quantidade certa em cada timer, para que acabem todos ao mesmo tempo.

Para isso é necessário:

- Saber o tempo total da animação e o tempo entre cada "frame" da animação
- Dividir o numero do contador pela quantidade total de "frames" da animação que irá dar quanto cada contador deve aumentar para acabar no tempo certo.

Tudo o resto é o que já tinha, apesar de ter retirado a função por ser um código muito curto e de ter trocado o `setTimeout` por [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Veja como ficou:

```js
const tempo_intervalo = 5; //ms -> define a velocidade da animação
const tempo = 4000; //ms -> define o tempo total da animaçao

$('.counter-up').each(function() {  
  let count_to = parseInt($(this).data('countTo'));
  let intervalos = tempo / tempo_intervalo; //quantos passos de animação tem
  let incremento = count_to / intervalos; //quanto cada contador deve aumentar
  let valor = 0;
  let el = $(this);
  
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (valor >= count_to){ //se já contou tudo tem de parar o timer
      valor = count_to;
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    
    let texto = valor.toFixed(0).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
    el.text(texto);
    valor += incremento;      
  }, tempo_intervalo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="counter-up" data-count-to="5684"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="counter-up" data-count-to="6603146"></span></div>
<div>
  <span class="counter-up" data-count-to="20362"></span>
</div>
```